# Elasticsearch incrase total_in_bytes Memory

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm running a single node on an Ubuntu machine. Currently I  have not enough space on my node.

```
"mem" : {
          "total_in_bytes" : 25217441792,
          "free_in_bytes" : 674197504,
          "used_in_bytes" : 24543244288,
          "free_percent" : 3,
          "used_percent" : 97
        }
```

On the other hand when I execute the command df -h , I see that I still have enough space on my linux server

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                12G   12G     0 100% /dev
tmpfs                              2,4G  1,5M  2,4G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  158G  110G   42G  73% / ***<=====***
tmpfs                               12G     0   12G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                               12G     0   12G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          974M  304M  603M  34% /boot
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--opt     206G   70G  127G  36% /opt***<=======***
tmpfs                              2,4G     0  2,4G   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop0                          64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1634
/dev/loop10                         56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2620
/dev/loop8                          64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1695
/dev/loop2                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2632
/dev/loop7                          92M   92M     0 100% /snap/lxd/23991
/dev/loop3                          50M   50M     0 100% /snap/snapd/17883
/dev/loop4                          92M   92M     0 100% /snap/lxd/24061
```

Please how can I increase the value of total_in_bytes ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df -h` shows disk space, not memory.

If you want to increase the memory heap you can modify the jvm.options file.

```
# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space 
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space 
-Xms4g
-Xmx4g
```

Here heap will be 4gb. The recommendation is to set this parameter to 50% of the physical ram of the node, and not more than 32GB.

You can read more about memory in Elasticsearch here:

https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-and-troubleshooting-elasticsearch-memory